# Antenna frequency rating matter? (For home devices)

Tags: rf, antenna, receiver

If devices transmit and receive at certain frequencies, and if you wanted / had to replace the antenna, do you have to use the same frequency rating?

Example: I have a garage door receiver, and the frequency is 300 mhz and I wanted to add an external antenna for better range. Would I need an antenna rated for 300 mhz, or would a higher rating do?

Comment: You'll also want to have the same impedance or won't matter much how well-tuned the antenna is to your frequency.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is mostly yes. Using an antenna outside its intended frequency band will almost surely degrade its gain and VSWR, leading to a *reduced* effective range.

I'd recommend using a **telescopic antenna**. You can adjust its length to tune it to your receiver frequency.

Look for one that has the same connector (BNC, SMA, whatever) and impedance that the one you plan to replace.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is yes. If you had to replace the antenna there are specs you would have to match. Antennas act like frequency filters and have a range that they transmit (and receive). The impedance that the radio receiver and\or transmitter sees needs to be matched to the antenna.

One problem is you may make the situation worse, and it may be against the law. Because consumer devices are tested by the FCC for compliance, modifying the antenna may be breaking the compliance. Another problem is you aren't going to get any more power out of the transmitter.

Answer (score 0):

All antenna has gain characteristic. It can received any signals so long the signal is within the antenna frequency range. All the non inband signals will suffer more heavy attenuation.

[image]

Above: The antenna gain of OmniLOG 70600. The antenna is supposed to be used from 680MHz - 6GHz, according to specs. There are performance penalties outside the range.

Comment: Yes, but what about impedance?

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely, that's correct. In simpler terms, the "frequency" refers to the resonant frequency of the antenna, which is crucial because it determines the specific frequency at which the antenna operates most efficiently. For improving the range, it's beneficial to choose an antenna with higher gain.